# how to work with joined RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

say that I have a text file called 1.txt and 2.txt. 
1.txt contains

```
1,9,5
2,7,4
3,8,3
```

and 2.txt contains

```
1,g,h
2,i,j
3,k,l
```

So, i joined the two by their keys(first column):

```
val one = sc.textFile("1.txt").map{
  line => val parts = line.split(",",-1)
    (parts(0),(parts(1),parts(2)))
}

val one = sc.textFile("2.txt").map{
  line => val parts = line.split(",",-1)
    (parts(0),(parts(1),parts(2)))
}
```

Now, if I understand this correctly, I'm getting

```
(1,  (  (9,5), (g,h)  ))
(2,  (  (7,4), (i,j)  ))
(3,  (  (8,3), (k,l)  ))
```

Now, say that I need to sum up all the values of the second column of 1.txt,

1. how do i do this?
2. How do I refer to the second column of 2.txt(i.e. g,i,k) in the joined RDD?
3. Is there any good tutorial for working with RDD ? I'm a spark(and scala) newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. joining is really easy `val joined = one.join(two)` (noticed you named both RDD's `one` for some reason, assuming you meant to give them different names)
2. [tuple syntax in scala](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-tuple-examples-syntax) is `tuple._number`, so to sum up the 1.txt colums if `joined` is the joined RDD you do
   `val sum = joined.map(_._2._1._2.toInt).reduce(_+_)` , might want to cast to long or even BigInt in the map if these files are really big.
3. I'd say the best tutorials for spark is their [main site](https://spark.apache.org), [amp camp stuff](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/matei-zaharia-amp-camp-2012-advanced-spark.pdf) and I personally like looking through the source and scaladocs. For scala "programming in scala" is a good start.

The whole program, slightly rewritten to use better scala style (disclaimer, not a scala expert)

```
val one = sc.textFile("1.txt").map{
  _.split(",", -1) match {
    case Array(a, b, c) => (a, ( b, c))
  }
}

val two = sc.textFile("2.txt").map{
    _.split(",", -1) match {
      case Array(a, b, c) => (a, (b, c)) 
    }
    //looks like these two map functions are the same, could refactor into a lambda or non member function
}

val joined = one.join(two)

val sum = joined.map {
     case (_, ((_, num2), (_, _))) => num2.toInt 
}.reduce(_ + _)
```

Comment: A perhaps more readable alternative to `map(_._2._1._2.toInt)` is `map { case (id, ((num1, num2), (str1, str2))) => num2.toInt }`.

Comment: Your style was *nearly* perfect ... you should use () whenever you have single line lambdas, and @DanielDarabos suggestion would make things way more readible. Finally, you should put spaces after commas and between operators. ... I'll try to edit your answer

Comment: Oh and +1 for remembering to use -1 in your split - unbelievable how many people forget about that!

Comment: @DanielDarabos took your suggestion

Comment: @samthebest most of ur edits were minor, but next time I'll run my program through scalastyle before submitting :). Besides you deleted my disclaimer, I can't have people thinking I'm a scala expert

Comment: If your only going to use `num2` then just leave the rest as `_` ... and please put in the spaces at the very least :) (spaces are not a minor edit in real life projects as auto-formatters will then break git diff and can cause nightmare merge conflicts)

Comment: thank you all VERY MUCH!! I like @DanielDarabos' comment about readability. Thank you all !!